# how to create a table like this by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, max, workbench

| ID | Payment | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 |
| A | 15 | 2 |
| A | 12 | 3 |
| B | 11 | 2 |
| B | 15 | 4 |
| C | 25 | 1 |
| C | 17 | 3 |

I'm looking for a query that returns a row for each ID for its last year. The year column is ordered increasing for each ID.

| ID | Payment | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 3 |
| B | 15 | 4 |
| C | 17 | 3 |

```
select ID, Payment, Year from payment_table
where year = (select max(year) from ?????????);
```

what shall I write instead of "????????"?

Comment: [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121387/3404097)

Answer (score 3):

Use `subquery` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where year = (select max(t1.year) from table t1 where t1.id = t.id);
```

Comment: `table` as a table name is probably a poor choice and can lead to confusion.

Comment: @shayan `select t.* from table t...` means you are selecting from a table named `table` and referring to that table as `t` in any subsequent expression. The inner `select max(t1.year) from table t1...` is a select from the same table named `table` and referring to that one as `t1` so as not to be confused with the results of the first select for `t`.

Comment: @shayan. . . `table` is dummy name of table & `t1` is a table alise. So, you just rename it with your original table name.

Comment: @shayan Replace `table` with `payment_table`.  Hopefully this is a production database that you mess around.  You seem to know nothing about SQL.  This is as one of the most basic query, and you can't even figure out what to change.  I suggest you stop messing around with it, and hire someone who knows database.